# Unable to maintain BLE connection - BlueZ Linux <-> iOS

Tags: ios, linux, bluetooth

**Setup:**

I'm running BlueZ 5.48 on an embedded Linux platform, with the Python `example-gatt-server` as a peripheral.  I enable advertising with `hciconfig hci0 leadv 0`.

I am trying to connect using `nRF Connect` from an iPhone (iOS v12.1.4).

The devices are both on my desk, measuring about -40dBm RSSI, so signal levels should be good.

**Issue(s):**

I'm aware of several issues, and will list them in priority order (highest first).

a) In `nRF Connect` on the iPhone, I *can* see the device and connect, but after 30-60 seconds something causes a disconnect.  It never asks me for permission to pair or enter a PIN.

b) In Linux, I see `Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available` printed repeatedly as long as the iPhone is connected.

c) On the iPhone, I cannot see my peripheral device in the regular Bluetooth `Devices` list...ever.  (This is a lesser issue...although I'd like to try pairing this way if possible.)

**What I've tried:**

1) I removed the `TestService` with secure / encrypted characteristics from the `example-gatt-server` Python code, so all that remain are `Heartrate` and `Battery` services.  The iPhone `nRF Connect` app still disconnects after 30-60 seconds.

2) To determine the cause of disconnect, I looked at the journal for `bluetooth.service` in Linux:

```
Mar 15 18:44:57 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/gatt-database.c:send_notification_to_device() GATT server sending notification
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device MAC_ADDR_HERE disconnected, reason 1
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: plugins/policy.c:disconnect_cb() reason 1
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr MAC_ADDR_HERE type 1 status 0xe
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding (nil) status 0x0e
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 14
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/device.c:att_disconnected_cb()
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/device.c:att_disconnected_cb() Connection timed out (110)
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x20d080: device MAC_ADDR_HERE profile batt-profile state changed: connected -> disconnecting (0)
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x20d080: device MAC_ADDR_HERE profile batt-profile state changed: disconnecting -> disconnected (0)
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x20d638: device MAC_ADDR_HERE profile deviceinfo state changed: connected -> disconnecting (0)
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x20d638: device MAC_ADDR_HERE profile deviceinfo state changed: disconnecting -> disconnected (0)
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x20ca00: device MAC_ADDR_HERE profile gap-profile state changed: connected -> disconnecting (0)
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x20ca00: device MAC_ADDR_HERE profile gap-profile state changed: disconnecting -> disconnected (0)
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/gatt-client.c:btd_gatt_client_disconnected() Device disconnected. Cleaning up.
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/device.c:att_disconnected_cb() Automatic connection disabled
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: attrib/gattrib.c:g_attrib_unref() 0x21e968: g_attrib_unref=0
Mar 15 18:44:58 sn0010 bluetoothd[775]: src/gatt-database.c:att_disconnected()
```

This seems to say a timeout occurred (reason 1).

3) I altered the default `conn_min_interval=24`, `conn_max_interval=40`, `supervision_timeout=42` values in Linux `sysfs` to match the Apple compatibility guidelines.  (Values were changed to `12`, `24`, and `200` explicitly.)  Rebooting and restarting Bluetooth with this didn't make any difference.

4) I tried issuing `btmgmt bredr off` and `btmgmt bondable off` before `hciconfig hci0 leadv 0`, but no change.

5) I ran `nRF Sniffer` but it didn't seem to capture disconnect events.  I can tell my peripheral is advertising by filtering on its BD addr as shown below:

[image: Sniffer]

6) I disabled the `example-gatt-server` altogether.  `nRF Connect` is still able to connect, but disconnects after 30-60 seconds again.  This seems to isolate the issue within the iOS app, the BlueZ stack, or lower Linux driver layers/configuration.

7) Connecting using `nRF Connect` for **Android** works fine and maintains a steady connection as long as I wish.

**Question**

Does anyone have advice for what to try next?

**EDIT 1:**

Per comment, I have run `btmon` on the Linux host while the iPhone is connected.  I enabled `notify` for `Heartrate` characteristic on the iPhone.  The log shows a disconnect due to timeout.

```
< ACL Data TX: Handle 128 flags 0x00 dlen 7             #4792 [hci0] 105.414362 
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2                                            
        Handle: 0x0016                                                          
> ACL Data RX: Handle 128 flags 0x02 dlen 9             #4793 [hci0] 105.466957 
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4                                          
        Read Request (0x0a)                                                     
        Handle: 0x0016                                                          
        Error: Insufficient Authentication (0x05)                               
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5  #4794 [hci0] 105.467019 
        Num handles: 1                                                          
        Handle: 128                                                             
        Count: 1                                                                
< ACL Data TX: Handle 128 flags 0x00 dlen 7             #4795 [hci0] 105.474721 
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2                                            
        Handle: 0x0016                                                          
< ACL Data TX: Handle 128 flags 0x00 dlen 11            #4796 [hci0] 105.564168 
      ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 6                               
        Handle: 0x000c                                                          
          Data: 0e7d6400                                                        
< ACL Data TX: Handle 128 flags 0x00 dlen 9             #4797 [hci0] 106.558967 
      ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 4                               
        Handle: 0x000c                                                          
          Data: 0665                                                            
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5  #4798 [hci0] 106.877481 
        Num handles: 1                                                          
        Handle: 128                                                             
        Count: 3                                                                
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4          #4799 [hci0] 106.877698 
        Status: Success (0x00)                                                  
        Handle: 128                                                             
        Reason: Connection Timeout (0x08)                                       
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8    {0x0001} [hci0] 106.877764 
        LE Address: 71:68:0B:72:0F:E9 (Resolvable)                              
        Reason: Connection timeout (0x01)                                       
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8    {0x0002} [hci0] 106.877764 
        LE Address: 71:68:0B:72:0F:E9 (Resolvable)                              
        Reason: Connection timeout (0x01)
```

Comment: Please run "btmon" instead of nrf sniffer from the Linux machine. That way you can see all packets and probably the reason it disconnects, and who disconnects. Both GATT and SMP has a 30 second timeout if it doesn't receive any response to a previous request.

Answer (score 1):

I believe my issue is solved by using values in accordance with the Apple design guidelines.  I edited and rebuilt the kernel so default Bluetooth params are as follows:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval 
12
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval 
12
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/supervision_timeout 
500
```

This appears to maintain a BLE connection between Linux and the iPhone for as long as I wish.

Note: In attempting to edit these parameters via sysfs before, I believe the settings were lost upon reboot...or otherwise did not get applied like I thought.  I had also used slightly different values (conn_max_interval = 24 vs 12 now).

Comment: Apparently the Bluetooth chips fail to communicate with each other with your previous connection parameters, causing the timeout. Either one of the radios is bad or the clock is bad (for keeping the synchronization). If you get your sniffer up and running, you can probably see which is the device to blame.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the min/max intervals are in units of 1.25 ms, so a value of 12 really means the interval is 15 ms. Similarly the supervision timeout unit is 10 ms, so 500 means 5000 ms.

Answer (score 1):

I notice your btmon logs have:

```
    Error: Insufficient Authentication (0x05)
```

As per [Bluez: pairing issue with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222740/bluez-pairing-issue-with-ios). Presumably this is still the case after you fix with the new params?

(BTW iOS only shows BREDR enabled devices that are discoverable or previously paired in the OS Devices list)

Comment: Unfortunately, "NoInputNoOutput" still doesn't work for me. It immediately throws Authentication Failed (0x05) after you click pair on iOS. Then it re-prompts over and over again. My only workaround is to use a custom agent that autosubmits "yes" with "KeyboardDisplay" (I'm using BLE instead of BREDR, btw)